# Problem using ksoap2 with Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I thought I'd have a crack at building an Android app having not done any Java for five years (I've been living in MS land).

So my first project was supposed to be something easy.  A simple login form that calls a WCF service that I already have from another project.

So I got the whole thing set up OK in Eclipse and the app is running in the AVD.  I have also identified that I need ksoap2 for soap communication as Android devices are constrained.

I have what is likely to be a simple problem, however.  When I run the app and attempt to simply create a new instance of the ksoap2 PropertyInfo class I get a whole bunch of ClassNotFoundExceptions for things like java.awt.Container and java.applet.Applet.

I'm obviously setting up my build path wrong somehow but can't figure it out.

BTW, I' using ksoap2 v2.4 from http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself.  It seems it was actually an issue in ksoap2 2.4.

I downloaded and used v2.3 and had no problems at all.  Something to be aware of I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the latest 2.5.1 release and report and problems on the issue tracker or the mailing list.